# edit frontmatter on documentclass{elsarticle}

Tags: elsarticle, front-matter

[image]I have been using Elsevier documentclass for my manuscript. but I don't like how the front matter has the title all the way to the top of the page.

I would like to have the title centered vertically and the abstract (encased in the two black lines) on the second page.

Is that possible?

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

 \usepackage{geometry}

 %% this is to get rid of the watermark
 % ------------------------------
 \makeatletter
 \def\ps@pprintTitle{%
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage\hfil}
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
 }
 \makeatother
 % ------------------------------

  \begin{document}

    \begin{frontmatter}
    
        \title {Title\tnoteref{t1}}
        \tnotetext[t1]{This is a note to the title}
        
        \author[1]{author1\corref{cor1}\fnref{fn1}}
        \ead{author1@university.com}
        
        \author[3]{author2\fnref{fn2}}
        \ead{author2@university.com}
        \author[3]{author3}
        \ead{author3@university.com}
        \author[4]{author4}
        \ead{author4@university.com}
        \author[1,2]{author5}
        \ead{author5@university.com}
        \author[4]{author6}
        \ead{author6@university.com}
        
        \cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author footnote}
        \fntext[fn1]{Footnote}
        \fntext[fn2]{Second footnote}
        
        \address[1]{University1}
        \address[2]{University1}
        \address[3]{University1}
        \address[4]{University1}
        
        \begin{abstract}
        
        this is the abstract
        
            \begin{keyword}
                keyword
            \end{keyword}
            
        \end{abstract}
        
    \end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you planning to submit this to ELS?  If yes, don't change how the title is formatted.  If no, why are you using elsarticle?  Is there some aspect of it that isn't handled by the standard article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It is a simplified code of the one used by `elsarticle.cls`, to be used with     `\documentclass{elsarticle}` and easily customizable (fonts, space separation, lines, etc).

It will work with options `1p`, `3p` and `5p` (two column). The latter has the abstract on a single page.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% ONLY for dummy text

\usepackage{showframe} % show the margins
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}


%%*********************************************************
\makeatletter   
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
\let\@oddhead\@empty
\let\@evenhead\@empty
\def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage\hfil}
\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot     
}   

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%     added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}%
    \resetTitleCounters%
    \ifnum\jtype=5\onecolumn\fi%  option 5p
    \centering\null \vfil %centering
    \Large\@title\par\vspace{18pt}%
    \normalsize\elsauthors\par\vspace{10pt}%
    \footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par%
    \gdef\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}%
    \printFirstPageNotes%   footnotes and others    
    \clearpage% abstract and keys in next page  
    \ifnum\jtype=5\null\vfil\else\vspace*{-\topskip} \fi%   % no space on top
    \hrule\vspace{12pt}%
    \ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vspace{10pt}\fi%
    \ifvoid\keybox\else\unvbox\keybox\par\vspace{10pt}\fi%
    \hrule\vspace{12pt}%    
     \ifnum\jtype=5\clearpage\twocolumn\fi %  option 5p
    }%
\makeatother    
%*********************************************************
    
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
    
    \title{Title of Your Manuscript\tnoteref{label1}}
    \tnotetext[label1]{This is a note to the title}
    
    \author[inst1]{Author One\corref{cor1}\fnref{label2}}
    \ead{email address}
    \ead[url]{home page}
    \fntext[label2]{This is a footnote}
    \cortext[cor1]{Test of the corresponding author footnote}
    
    \affiliation[inst1]{organization={Department One},
    addressline={Address One}, 
    city={City One},
    postcode={00000}, 
    state={State One},
    country={Country One}}
    
    \author[inst2]{Author Two}
    \author[inst1,inst2]{Author Three\fnref{label3}}
    \fntext[label3]{This is a another footnote}
    
    \affiliation[inst2]{organization={Department Two},
    addressline={Address Two}, 
    city={City Two},
    postcode={22222}, 
    state={State Two},
    country={Country Two}}
    
    \begin{abstract}
    \kant[9]
    \end{abstract}  

\end{frontmatter}   

\section{Sample Section 1}
\label{sec:sample1}

1. \kant[2-15]

\end{document}
```

[image: e]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is at the preprint/pre-publication stage; you're not preparing the final document for publication.

Unfortunately, `elsarticle.cls` doesn't seem to be compatible with the `titling` package, so your only option would be to redefine the command from the document class (in this case, `\pprintMaketitle`).

Here is a modification I made. The lines I added to the original definition in the document class are marked with `% ADDED BY ME`. Basically, I just added [`\vfill`](https://latexref.xyz/_005cvfill.html) commands to put an even amount of space before the title/authors/affiliations and after them, and a `\clearpage` to start a new page for the abstract.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

 \usepackage{geometry}

 %% this is to get rid of the watermark
 % ------------------------------
 \makeatletter
 \def\ps@pprintTitle{%
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage\hfil}
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
 }

\long\def\pprintMaketitle{\clearpage
  \iflongmktitle\if@twocolumn\let\columnwidth=\textwidth\fi\fi
  \resetTitleCounters
  \def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \printFirstPageNotes
  \begin{\elsarticletitlealign}%
 \thispagestyle{pprintTitle}%
    \leavevmode\vfill % ADDED BY ME
   \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \Large\@title\par\vskip18pt%
    \ifx\@elsarticlenewpageafter\newpage@after@title% %*%
      \newpage
    \fi%
    \ifdoubleblind
      \vspace*{2pc}
    \else
      \normalsize\elsauthors\par\vskip10pt
      \footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt
    \fi
    \ifx\@elsarticlenewpageafter\newpage@after@author% %*%
      \newpage
    \fi%
    \vfill % ADDED BY ME
    \clearpage % ADDED BY ME
    \hrule\vskip12pt
    \ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    \ifvoid\keybox\else\unvbox\keybox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    \hrule\vskip12pt
    \ifx\@elsarticlenewpageafter\newpage@after@abstract% %*%
      \newpage
    \fi%
    \end{\elsarticletitlealign}%
    \gdef\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}%
  }


 \makeatother
 % ------------------------------
      
  \begin{document}

   \begin{frontmatter}

        \title {Title\tnoteref{t1}}

        \tnotetext[t1]{This is a note to the title}
        
        \author[1]{author1\corref{cor1}\fnref{fn1}}
        \ead{author1@university.com}
        
        \author[3]{author2\fnref{fn2}}
        \ead{author2@university.com}
        \author[3]{author3}
        \ead{author3@university.com}
        \author[4]{author4}
        \ead{author4@university.com}
        \author[1,2]{author5}
        \ead{author5@university.com}
        \author[4]{author6}
        \ead{author6@university.com}
        
        \cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author footnote}
        \fntext[fn1]{Footnote}
        \fntext[fn2]{Second footnote}
        
        \address[1]{University1}
        \address[2]{University1}
        \address[3]{University1}
        \address[4]{University1}

    \begin{abstract}
        
        this is the abstract
        
            \begin{keyword}
                keyword
            \end{keyword}
            
        \end{abstract}

    \end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

The redefinition must be surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` but since you were already using one of those, I just stuck it in after your other redefinition.

[image: revised elsarticle title page]